# ¿Cómo redactar/actualizar la información de etiqueta de elementos declarados obsoletos?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, extracto-de-etiquetas

Acabo de crear (porque no existía) la [información de etiqueta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/progressdialog/info) de la etiqueta [progressdialog](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/progressdialog) referente al componente `ProgressDialog` de Android, el cual ha sido declarado obsoleto.

Se me ha ocurrido poner de forma visible lo siguiente, al principio de la descripción informativa:

> Se desaconseja su uso. 
>   Es un componente de la interfaz gráfica de Android, 
>   declarado obsoleto desde la API 26.
>
> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Consideran que está bien así?**

**¿Sería una práctica que se podría llevar a cabo con etiquetas más importantes (con más preguntas) de elementos igualmente declarados obsoletos?**

Comment: En mi opinión, esa información debería ir dentro del cuerpo de la descripción de la información de la etiqueta (como veo que ya has puesto). La otra parte es una orientación de uso, y solo debería indicar en que casos debe usarse la etiqueta. A pesar de ser obsoleto, es posible que sigan surgiendo preguntas sobre el tema.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @Pikoh. Que sea obsoleto o no es independiente de la pregunta. Al decir _se desaconseja su uso_ parece que se desaconseje usar la etiqueta, cuando lo _malo_ es el componente. Eso sí, es bueno e incluso recomendable señalarlo en la wiki de la etiqueta.